# How can I use Rspec to check for the absence of certain CSS classes?

Tags: css, rspec, css-selectors, nokogiri

How can I use Rspec's `have_selector` to verify the that a DOM element does not have certain CSS classes?

I'm trying to use CSS syntax for this, but apparently Nokogiri doesn't support `:not()` selectors.

For example:

```
it "should not add any class to other inputs" do
  @buffer.output.should have_selector(
    'form input#monster_battle_cry:not(.integer, .decimal, .date, .phone, .zip)'
  )
end
```

This fails with `#Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: # unexpected ':not('`

Comment: The comma-separated syntax of `:not()` is non-standard (as of CSS3), so I'm not too sure if Nokogiri supports that syntax or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is ugly but should work:

```
it "should not add any class to other inputs" do
  @buffer.output.should have_xpath(
    "//form//input[@id='monster_battle_cry'][not(contains(@class, 'integer'))]"
  )
end
```

repeat `[not(contains(@class, 'integer'))]` with other classes.

**Edit** Oops, CSS should work also, only like this: `:not(.integer):not(.decimal)...`

**Edit again** No it doesn't and there is an open ticket for this: [CSS selector with multiple :not fails](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues/451)